# Input variables not updating inside downloadHandler for Shiny

Tags: r, input, scope, shiny

I am trying to output either a .html or .csv file depending on a radio input button by the user but the input is not updating inside the downloadHandler. It stays on the default value selected.

```
output$bidownload <- downloadHandler(


  if(input$conreport == 'report') {
    filename = paste0(input$conreport, '.html')
  } else {
    filename = paste0(input$conreport, '.csv')
  },
  content = function(file) {
    if(as.character(input$reporttype) == 'report') {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0(input$conreport, '.Rmd'))
      file.copy(paste0(input$conreport, '.Rmd'), tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      params <- list(range = as.character(input$dateparam))

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    } else {
      write.csv(weightbreak_raw(), file)
    }
  }
)
```

Since the selected radiobutton is on 'report', I will always produce an .html document even if the user changes the radio button. How do I get the input to update in the downloadhandler? I checked [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) and still cannot figure out how to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`downloadHandler` filename argument is either a string or a function. If you use a string, it is evaluated at render time but if you use a function it will be evaluated at download time (so after user select the desired type of download) :

```
output$bidownload <- downloadHandler(
  function(){
    if(input$conreport == 'report') 
      paste0(input$conreport, '.html')
    else
      paste0(input$conreport, '.csv')
  },
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did that and it works perfectly now.